# Javascript Map function does not preserve the original object

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario wherein i have

```
var data = [
    {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 0.27,
        "classifier": 1
    },
    {
        "x": 2,
        "y": 0.88,
        "classifier": 1
    }
]
```

I want another object data2 with y=1-y, which i obtain with:

```
var data2 = data.map(function(el) {el.y = 1-el.y; return el});

data2[0]
Object {x: 1, y: 0.73, classifier: 1}

data2[1]
Object {x: 2, y: 0.12, classifier: 1}
```

which is the correct form that i want the data in. However the issue is i want to preserve the original data as well. Right now even data has mutated data.

```
data[0]
Object {x: 1, y: 0.73, classifier: 1}

data[1]
Object {x: 2, y: 0.12, classifier: 1}
```

Is map the right function to use here? Am i using it correctly?

Comment: The array is preserved, and a new array is returned, but you're using the same objects, which are changed in both arrays because it's the same object

Comment: Clone your original object and make changes on the clone and return the changed clone to preserve your original data. In general, your map function should be non-interfering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating a new array, you let its values point to the original objects, which you mutate by assigning to their object properties.

Instead you could also create (shallow) copies of the objects with `Object.assign`:

```
var data2 = data.map(function(el) { 
    return Object.assign({}, el, { y: 1-el.y });
});
```

Or with arrow function:

```
var data2 = data.map( el => Object.assign({}, el, { y: 1-el.y }) );
```

```js
var data = [
    {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 0.27,
        "classifier": 1
    },
    {
        "x": 2,
        "y": 0.88,
        "classifier": 1
    }
]
var data2 = data.map( el => Object.assign({}, el, { y: 1-el.y }) );

console.log (data);
```

Comment: Thank you! It answers my question, though it raises a couple more. If i may ask, is there any benefit for making a shallow copy of the object as opposed to the deep copy that @JosephYoung mentioned in his answer?

Comment: The depth of the copy is really for you to decide and depends very much on the purpose of your code. In your example data it would not matter as you have not any more depth in the objects. Your property values are primitive values.

Answer (score 1):

You're modifying the original element object, which isn't a full deep copy of the original data.

Create a copy of el in the function and then calculate the new `.y`. For example:

```
var data2 = data.map(function(el) {
  return {
    x : el.x,
    y : 1-el.y,
    classifier : el.classifier
  };
});
```

Comment: Perfect makes sense! Thank you. I had a funny feeling the map anonymous function was incorrect but couldnt understand why!